# Finding center of mass coordinates

Tags: calculus

I'm working triple integrals but I have some conflicts with finding coordinates of center of mass. I read a question and start thinking about it but I can not reach any solution. I need only some hint about it.

**Question:** An homogeneous object placed to in the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ to region which all $x$-$y$-$z$ coordinates are positive. Find the center of mass coordinates of object.

Comment: What is known about the object?

Comment: It is homogeneous, I edited my question.

Comment: In other words the object is 1/8 of the sphere?

Comment: What is geometry & dimensions of the object placed inside the sphere. Mere object volume $\frac18$ of sphere volume is not sufficient enough to find out C.M.

Answer (score 1):

The $z$ coordinate of C.M. for $\frac18$ of the sphere is:
$$
\bar z=\frac{\int_V z\, dV}{V}=\frac{\frac{\pi a^4}{16}}{\frac18\frac{4\pi}3a^3}=\frac38a,\tag1
$$
where the integral is most easily computed in the spherical coordinates $(z=r\cos\theta)$:
$$
\int_V z\, dV=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}d\phi\int_0^a r\,r^2 dr\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\cos\theta\sin\theta d\theta=\frac\pi2\frac{a^4}4\frac12.
$$

By symmetry the same value will be obtained for $\bar x$ and $\bar y$.

Comment: Can we user $a$ instead of $R$?

Comment: Of course. Done.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Coordinates of the center of a homogeneous solid are:

$$x_C=\frac{\int\limits_V x dV}{V}, \quad y_C=\frac{\int\limits_V y dV}{V}, \quad z_C=\frac{\int\limits_V z dV}{V}.$$

Comment: I cant sure how to determine the region V. Actually region is  1/8 of our sphere. That's why i got confused.

Comment: I will recommend spherical coordinates. You will have these limits: $0 \le r \le a$, $0 \le \varphi \le \pi/2$ and $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$.